# how to wait untill the data is sent Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a little problem, I'm implemented a sign out button, the thing is that when I press the button to logout the app crashes because my user now is null and meanwhile it's uploading to the database some files, so at the time it needs to reach the user to post the data, the user is null. is there a way to know or wait till the uploads to firebase are done and then logout, or I need to implement a timer?

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(
                            prefs.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();

                }

            }
        };
```

I have this listeners all over the place to check if the user is logged in or not.

And this is my signout button

```
  Preference button = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_header_cerrar_sesion));
                button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {


                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        finish();


                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: signOut() doesn't have a callback. I think Firebase automatically manages it with Local data persistence.So no worry to Sign out Fail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait, you need to know when the data has been committed. For that you can add a `completion listener`. Both methods, setValue() and updateChildren(), take an optional completion listener that is called when the write has been committed to the database. To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
yourRef.setValue("I'm writing data", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so in the oncompletion i need to put the firebase.signout

Comment: The flow is like this: Write data to database -> add CompletionListener -> When onComplete method is called and there is no error -> do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make a progress dialog and show it in send request. After that dismiss it in onSuccess method

```
mDatabase.child(card).setValue(request).addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
         //dismiss dialog
        }
});
```